# How to reduce the spaces between columns in datatable object from DT R package?

Tags: r, dt

I would like to reduce the spaces between columns in datable object (DT package from R language). Please see below example:

```
datatable(iris)
```

[image: iris_datatable]

Comment: `library(DT);datatable(iris)` returns `Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper that is an error on your end.

Comment: The data table is designed to fill its width.  You can tweak with the width and height parameter to get the data table sided the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Could you provide me some details? What do you mean by 'tweak with the width and height parameter' - have I use some java script code or just datatable arguments?